# Ctx is a required argument that is missing discrd.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

These 4 code are from the same group

the `create_voice`(make v) and `create_nsfw`(make n) is working

the `create_text`(make t) and `create_channel`(make c) is not working

The `text` and `channel` function don't get the context that should be pass but the `voice` and `nsfw` work just fine

Don't mind the Namerror I just want to demonstrate that it is weird that it is in the same syntax but 1/2 of them didn't work

```
@commands.group()
async def make(self, ctx):
    """make channel c,t,v,n [name]"""
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send('Invalid sub command passed...')
```

```
@make.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['category'])
async def c(self, ctx, name):
    """create Category"""
    existing_category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    if existing_category is None:
        await ctx.create_category_channel(name=name)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Creating {name}", color=0x5cbac4, timestamp=datetime.now())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(f"{discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name).mention}")
    else:
        ctx.send(f"{name} already exists")
```

```
@make.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['text', "Text"])
async def t(self, ctx, name, category=None):
     """create Text channel"""
     channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name, category=category)
     if channel is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=name, category=category)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Creating {name}: ", color=0x5cbac4,
                              timestamp=datetime.now())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(f"{discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name).mention}")
     else:
        ctx.send(f"{name} already exists")
```

```
@make.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['voice', "Voice"])
async def v(self, ctx, name, category=None):
     """create Voice channel"""
     channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name, category=category)
     if existing_channel is None:
         await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name=name, category=category)
         embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Creating {name}: ", color=0x5cbac4,
                               timestamp=datetime.now())
         await ctx.send(embed=embed)
         await ctx.send(f"{discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name).mention}")
     else:
         ctx.send(f"{name} already exists")
```

```
@make.command(pass_contex=True, aliases=['nsfw', "NSFW"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def n(self, ctx, name, category=None):
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name, category=category)
    if existing_channel is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=name, category=category, nsfw=True)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Creating {name}:", color=0x5cbac4, timestamp=datetime.now())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(f"{discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=name).mention}")
    else:
        ctx.send(f"{name} already exists")
```

[image: My result in discord.py]

Comment: Have you passed a name? It has to be `make t NAME`. Als try to add `invoke_without_command=True` to `@commands.group()`

Comment: if i do `$make t nam` it comes up with name is a required arguement (since i already prase name in it i dont understand why) after that i check `ctx is t` `name is nam` @Dominik

Comment: Do you have another command named `t`? maybe in another group, if so rename the funktion to for example `make_t` and set the commands name to `t`

Comment: @Guddi its working now thanks a lot i have another group call remove which contain c and t function. after that it was completely fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was making a mistake naming the same function in a different group.